# How to change line perspective using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to be able to sharpen my line using CSS only. I was wondering if the transform property will allow that with a cross-browser fit.

[image]

I am a bit troubled since I know that this is possible using gradient `background` on my div, but the background property cannot be changed for my app. Is there any way to use `transform` to do that?

```css
.element {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg); /* would perspective property help ? */
  left: 110px;
  top: 0px;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0); /* cannot be changed */
  width: 1px;
  height: 243px;
  border: 0px solid red;  /* cannot be changed */
  /* you can add more property too */
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: Is your background that this line sits on top of a solid color or is it an image or something?

Comment: .element is a div with a red background as you can see on the snippet

Comment: Yes, but what about what's behind `.element`? Its parent elements. Does it sit on top of something?

Comment: The parent is another div named .elements with an absolute position, the width and height of it is fixed and immutable.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to ask is: are you trying to fade the line from red to white, or are you trying to achieve true opacity where you can see through the line to whatever is behind it?

Comment: @cjl750 I see, any solution is good with me, it could be faded, or just sharpened changing it's persepective so there are no rules on that, as long as it's sharp or faded or gradient on every angles.

Comment: You said you cannot use gradient background, but can you use an inset box-shadow (white shadow)?

Comment: @PascalGoldback of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot directly change the `background`, you could overlay a pseudo element on top of it instead. Use a linear gradient in the pseudo element's background.

```css
.element {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg); /* would perspective property help ? */
  left: 110px;
  top: 0px;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0); /* cannot be changed */
  width: 1px;
  height: 243px;
  border: 0px solid red;  /* cannot be changed */
  /* you can add more property too */
}
.element::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, white);
  width: 1px;
  height: 243px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: This seems nice, I will give it a try and keep you up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is what you can achieve with perspective:

```css
.element {
  position: absolute;
  transform: perspective(7px) rotate(135deg) rotateX(15deg); /* would perspective property help ? */
  transform-origin: right center;
  left: 110px;
  top: 0px;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0); /* cannot be changed */
  width: 1px;
  height: 243px;
  border: 0px solid red;  /* cannot be changed */
  /* you can add more property too */
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to detach it from the border? Seems like I can't put it in the centre of the screen without it touching the borders, see https://jsfiddle.net/8e9fn7L2/

Answer (score -1):

yes,of course,the property `transform` can be used cross browser,but you should add the prefix:

```
transform:rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(7deg);     /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(7deg);    /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Safari 和 Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(7deg);  /* Opera */
```

to achieve this effect,you should use the property `linear-gradient` instead of the transform property.

```
.element {
            position: absolute;
            transform: rotate(135deg);
            left: 110px;
            top: 0px;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
            width: 1px;
            height: 243px;
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the background value cannot be changed by human, since there's loads of js and python setting values for it. That's why I am asking for another solution than this one.

Comment: would you try canvas to draw it ?

Comment: I've had this long reflection about using canvas (fabricjs) for my app, but unfortunately there's no way I can use it and it's not good for the perf of my project. Everything will be with HTML/CSS